# Py_Finalize does not reset environment

Tags: python, c

My C code periodically loads a Python script and runs it using Python 3's high level bindings. The script runs fine the first time but subsequently fails with a syntax error where the only variable is declared.

The variable is declared in my script as an empty list so I would guess that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html) note suggesting that `Py_Finalize()` does not properly reset some libraries, does not apply here:

Relevant line in Python script:
`result = list()`

My code:

```
PyObject *eval_module;
PyObject *eval_dict;
PyObject *eval_value;
char *ret;

Py_Initialize();

PyRun_SimpleString(script);
eval_module = PyImport_AddModule((char *) "__main__");
eval_dict   = PyModule_GetDict(eval_module);
eval_value  = PyDict_GetItemString(eval_dict, "output");

char *python_ret = PyBytes_AsString(eval_value);
if(python_ret != NULL) {
    python_ret = strdup(python_ret);
    Py_Finalize();
    return python_ret;
}
Py_Finalize();
return NULL;
```

I also tried putting `Py_Finalize()` just before `Py_Initialize()` which did not help.

Comment: Python does not support it well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10206833/3786245. Why not just call ```Py_Initialize``` at the program start and ```Py_Finalize``` at then end?

Comment: I am running the same code more than once so it seemed practical to call `Py_Finalize()` after executing the code and reinitialise to make sure that I get a clean environment.

Comment: If you correctly release objects, the environment should be the same each time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by correctly release?

Comment: Something like ```Py_XDECREF()```